# Delegate returning type object does not accept function returning Guid

Tags: c#

When returning the following function

```
public Guid GetUserFilterValue( string filterID )
```

As

```
Func<string, object>
```

I am getting the error that it has the wrong return type. If I change the return type to anything other than Guid it compiles. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would usually work if the return type was a reference type, because `Func<T, TResult>` is covariant for T; but `Guid` is a value type, this is why your method is not a valid candidate for `Func<string, object>`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx):

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

As a workaround, you could use a lambda expression:

```
Func<string, object> f = filterId => GetUserFilterValue(filterId);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Guid` is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), and thus does not have a binary representation compatible with that of `object`. If you need to adapt this method to the given signature you need to write a wrapper function that [boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the `Guid` into an object:

```
Func<string, object> f = s => (object)GetUserFilterValue(s);
```